# Can't make a foreach run simultaneously

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0, foreach

I've been trying to run a loop that does the same logic for every variable simultaneously.
I've been trying it with the foreach loop but instead of doing it simultaneously, it takes one value at a time and executes the logic for it and then passes to the next one instead of doing it at the same time for all of them.
Let's take this as an example:

```
public static ArrayList MyFamily = new ArrayList() { "Me", "Mom", "Dad", "Brother" }
public static bool SayPrayer = false;
public static bool PickUpTheFork = false;
public static bool StartEating = false;
```

Now let's say I want to make all my family behave at dinner in the same way at the each same time:

```
public static void Dinner ()
{
    foreach (string Person in MyFamily)
    {
        SayPrayer = true;
        Thread.Sleep(30000);
        SayPrayer = false;
        PickUpTheFork = true;
        Thread.Sleep(3000)
        PickUpTheFork = false;
        StartEating = true;
    }
}
```

I've figured that if I make distinct foreach loops for each actions and put the thread.sleep between them (outside the loops) it works in somehow. However, is there a easier way to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think each person isn't being updated simultaneously (since the variables are static and don't belong to a single person: once `SayPrayer` is set, then everyone would be saying a prayer). Can you elaborate on how you're debugging it?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the [task parallel library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.100).aspx), the `Parallel.ForEach` method does exactly what you're asking for.

```
Parallel.ForEach(MyFamily, (person) => {
    // perform operations
});
```

**Edit:** Since it came up in the comments, I'll mention it up here: your operations will run *simultaneously* but that may not require each task on its own *thread*.  The TPL *will* attempt to run those operations on every member of the `MyFamily` collection as concurrently as possible.

Comment: Note this isn't guaranteed to spawn a thread per person. It'll work, but only sometimes. A loop for each action is really the only logical way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would define a static variable for each of these booleans in your Person class.

```
public class Person{
    public static bool SayPrayer = false;
    public static bool PickUpFork = false;
    public static bool StartEating = false;
    //...
}
```

and then you could simply set these static variables, which would apply to each member of the MyFamily collection...

```
    Person.SayPrayer = true;
    Thread.Sleep(30000);
    Person.SayPrayer = false;
    Person.PickUpTheFork = true;
    Thread.Sleep(3000)
    Person.PickUpTheFork = false;
    Person.StartEating = true;
```

This is a clean(and memory efficient) way to perform the operation you describe without iterations or 3rd party libraries.